# sessionstorage to avoid owerwriting the data

Tags: javascript, forms, session-storage

Hye,
I would like to know how to avoid overwriting the data logged in sessionStorage each time forms are validated. I would like to keep all the data each time sending
Thank you in advance for your help !

```
document.getElementById('submitNewRestaurant').onclick = function register() {

   if(typeof sessionStorage!='undefined' && JSON) {
        var restaurant = {
            restaurantName:document.getElementById('newName').value,
            adresse:document.getElementById('newAddress').value
        };
        sessionStorage.setItem('coord',JSON.stringify(restaurant));

}


    document.getElementById('submitbtn').onclick  = function register() {


    if(typeof sessionStorage!='undefined' && JSON) {
        var resto= {
            fullcomment:document.getElementById('fullcomment').value,
        };
        sessionStorage.setItem('view',JSON.stringify(resto));

    }


$(function () {

            $("#submitbtn").click(function () {
                var item = $("#numberstars option:selected").text();
                sessionStorage.setItem("stars", item);
            });
            sessionStorage.setItem('stars',JSON.stringify(item));

       });
```

Comment: Use arrays of objects instead of plain objects, maybe?

Comment: Push your objects into an array, instead of using .setItem use sessionStorage[key].push(), but previously you have to define it as an array

Answer (score 0):

It 's ok, I found, thank you !:

```
names = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('nom') || "[]");
addresses= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('adresse') || "[]");
document.getElementById('submitNewRestaurant').onclick =function (saveData) {

  var data = document.getElementById('newName').value;
  names.push(data);
  sessionStorage.setItem('nom', JSON.stringify(names));

  var data = document.getElementById('newAddress').value;
  addresses.push(data);
  sessionStorage.setItem('adresse', JSON.stringify(addresses));

    };

    views = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('commentaire') || "[]");
    notes = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('note') || "[]");
document.getElementById('submitbtn').onclick =function (saveData) {

  var data = document.getElementById('fullcomment').value;
  views.push(data);
  sessionStorage.setItem('commentaire', JSON.stringify(views));

  var data= $('#numberstars option:selected').text();
               sessionStorage.setItem('note',data);
               sessionStorage.setItem('note',JSON.stringify(data));
  notes.push(data);
  sessionStorage.setItem('note', JSON.stringify(notes));
};
```